# Client does not refresh the data sent from Server

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization, while-loop

I have problem with update my serialized objects. Client does not refresh the data sent from Server. I created loop in Client but it still dont update.

```
    public void run(){
              try {
                    socket = new Socket(host.getText(), new Integer(port.getText()));
                    wyswietlKomunikat("Connected.");
```

I created loop in Client but it still dont update.

```
             // Serialization      
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while(true){
             Pakiet p = (Pakiet) ois.readObject();
             showHome(p.getHome());
             ShowAway(p.getAway());
             showHomeLine(p.getShowHomeLine());
             showAwayLine(p.getShowHomeLine());

             // end of serialization

                    in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());                    
                    while(in.hasNextLine()){
                            showComment(in.nextLine());
                    }
              }
            }

      catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            showComment("no connection!");

      }
      catch (IOException e) {
            showComment(e.toString());
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
      finally {
             try {
                  socket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
// loop forever
while(true) {
    // check if there is something new
    if (in.hasNextLine()) {
        // there is, read it
        showComment(in.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be any different to just calling nextLine().

Comment: Actually, I've added an infinite loop, and yes, the answer is accepted and yes, it makes difference.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you are mixing the use of two kinds of stream on the same socket. Don't do that. Because of buffering, the streams can 'steal' data from each other. Keep using the object streams, or don't use the, at all and just and lines, bytes, whatever you want.

You may also be running into the problem for which ObjectOutputStream.reset() is the solution: see its Javadoc.